# Fragment View not updating

Tags: android, android-fragments

The issue i am running in to is something i have tried to search for continuously.

I have a `fragment(FRAGMENT A)` that I use to load custom views in too. Each of those views contain textviews which are populated by running an asynctask to get values. Now I have a button that i use to load a new `fragment(FRAGMENT B)` which allows me to edit one of those values in my custom views and then it calls popbackstack going back to `(FRAGMENT A)`. `onResume(Fragment A)`.

I rerun the async task to get the new values but it does not update.

I have tried multiple things but it does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: make sure your fragment b success to save data first.

Comment: Ru sure that values are coming in onResume(). print that and check it.

Comment: Make sure you do any task that depends on the asynctask in the onPostexecute method of the asynctask because its the only place you can be sure to have updated values from the asynctask. asynctask runs in separate thread and doesn't block the rest of the program from execution.

Comment: I verified that the data has been successfully added to the db. I am not sure what you mean by if the values are coming in. I do see the procedure run and the views regenerate but the values do not seem to be updated. everything that i need is being done in post execute.

Comment: Now u need to show ur code .

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around that was to simply put a small delay before running the get values procedure after the FRAGMENT B comes back to FRAGMENT A.